# How to dynamically insert jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

I am trying use jQuery's rich animation features on dynamically loaded content.

I can dynamically insert script into an element like so:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = "some html here";

var script  = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.text = 'alert("Alert!");';

element.appendChild (script);
```

The problem occurs when I try to insert jquery code into the script element. This does not work and causes the script to not run at all.

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = "some html here";

var script  = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.text = 'alert("Alert!");\n';
script.text = script.text+'$("div").animate({height:300,opacity:0.4},"slow");\n';

element.appendChild (script);
```

I can successfully append javascript code to change the elements I want, but using jquery functions will simplify things.

With firebug I can see the script elements has been loaded into the dom, however when I add the jquery code to it, nothing happens, not even the alert.

I have included the jquery source file in my main document and wrapped all of my code into a window.addEventListener('load', function()) to call the functions that initiates the code above when the page finishes loading.

Is there a way to dynamically create calls to jquery functions? Am I going about this the right way? I've been stumped for a while and google hasnt solved this one for me, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what is your goal, but this approach seems the most unmaintainable ever - just define your functions, then call them on appropriate events [async load, element creation, user actions...].

Comment: Maybe look at your `script.text` value assignments.  Seems you need some semicolon action in there after the `alert()`.

Comment: @Mike thanks for the catch, simple type on this form. I had them right in my original code.

Comment: @moonwave99, im working on an ajax site that pulls user data in xml format from a server via php. That data gets parsed and showed to the user in various ways. I wish to use ajax to load pages asynchronously and jquery for the transition animations.

Comment: @Gabe just write down your code :) You don't need to create `<script>` wrappers to get it executed - [have a look here to get started](http://jqfundamentals.com/).

Comment: @moonwave99, thanks for your help thus far. I have my js functions in an external .js file that is linked to my index along with jquery. Will I be able to use jquery functions in my js file? I did what you suggested but it still doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$('body').append('<s' + 'cript>console.log("lol");</script>');
```

But why are you not wrapping your code into a function which you can then call whenever you please?

```
function iAnimateThings() {
   $("div").animate({height:300,opacity:0.4},"slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey nothing wrong with your code you just missed one single inverted comma on this line

```
script.text = script.text+'$("div").animate({height:300,opacity:0.4},"slow")';
```

here is your working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vYut9/